# Crontab doesn't have permission to read a file

Tags: python, linux, cron

i need to calculate the percentage difference between yesterday bitcoin price and current price.

I have a python script and the current price is given by:

```
 response = requests.get('http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
```

but i don't know how to get yesterday price. The only way that i found is saving the current price in a txt file and updating it every day. The problem is with crontab that doesn't have the access to the file and can't read this line.

```
file = open("yesprice.txt", "r")
```

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`chmod a+r yesprice.txt` Should do the trick.